# Relative path as an input of InputStream

Tags: java, file, file-io

How can I read a file from a relative path?

I´ve tried this, but without success:

```
package es;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class Principal {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("/prueba/src/es/myFile.txt");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    }

}
```

And my project is as simple as:

[image: Project screenshot]

The error I obtained is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: \prueba\src\es\myFile.txt (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at es.Principal.main(Principal.java:13)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using separator explicitly use separator constant from File class.

Comment: File.Separator. Thant´s better. Nonetheless, The JVM will re-interpret it, independently of the operative system used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:

The relative path should be:

```
File file = new File("src/es/myFile.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

`"/prueba/src/es/myFile.txt"`is an absolute path not relative. Remove intial `'/'`to get a relative path.